# gitosis authorized keys

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis

Strange thing - on git push gitosis does not adds key for new user to the /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys. Of course - i can add keys manually, but its not good :(

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to solve this problem i've used

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```

Answer (score 2):

This also happens if you forget to add .pub to the end of your key file in the keydir, which kept me entertained for a while ...